# Неожидаемый результат конкатенации "||" оператором CLOB с NULL строкой

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c, clob

Недавно заметил, что приведенный ниже код, после обновления до версии 19c, ведет себя не так, как ожидалось:

```
declare
    nullval varchar2 (1) := null;
    clobval clob := '1234567890';
    someval varchar2(10) := '{test}';
    result varchar2 (32) := nullval||clobval||someval;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line ('result='||result);
end;
/
result={test}7890
```

Но это очевидно, что результат должен был быть: `1234567890{test}`.

Кто-нибудь знает причину? Есть ли какая-нибудь функция обновления БД, или какое-то решение?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Concatenate CLOB with null strings using "||" in PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62887563) от участника [@K Chiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11596750/k-chiu)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62887563

Comment: Подозрительно похожий [баг на MOS: Doc ID 2663093.1](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2663093_1.html).

Answer (score 2):

Это уже известный баг, добавте пустую строку в начало:

```sql
declare
    nullval varchar2 (1) := null;
    clobval clob := '1234567890';
    someval varchar2(10) := '{test}';
    result varchar2 (32) := ''||nullval||clobval||someval;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line ('result='||result);
end;
/
result=1234567890{test}
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62887928) от участника [@Sayan Malakshinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/429100/sayan-malakshinov)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Так как, результат конкантенации всегда будет `VARCHAR2`, то лучше извлечь содержимое `CLOB` как `VARCHAR2` с макс. длиной исходя из макс. длин значений результата, других переменных, а также из замечаний к функции по длине возвращаемого символьного буфера [`DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_LOB.html#GUID-F0F5D13A-C86C-4BC2-8394-8CBA3344D5CE) касателльно установленой кодировки. Так будет работать:

```
declare
    nullval varchar2 (1) := null;
    clobval clob := '1234567890';
    someval varchar2(10) := '{test}';
    result varchar2 (128); 
begin
    result := nullval||dbms_lob.substr (clobval, 96)||someval;
    dbms_output.put_line ('result='||result);
end;
/

result=1234567890{test}
```

И кроме того, это даст возможность избежать ошибки переполнения буфера:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small